# UIBotton on top of UIPopoverController disappears

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am making a photo slide show app for iPAD. I let users select their photos by popping open UIPopoverController. To that pop-up I added a custom button called "Done". Now here where it gets wacky. When the pop-up is launched for the first time you see the "Done" button. When I click on the photo album, the done button disappears and if I go back to the main photo selection page, it disappears from there too. See screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the code that i am using. What in the world is going on here? I think I have the code right.

```
-(IBAction)selectExitingPicture
{
    //Specially for iPAD
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 300.0) 
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                           animated:YES];

}


- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

    NSLog(@"Inside navigationController ...");

    // add done button to right side of nav bar
    doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  target:self action:@selector(saveImages:)];

    bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    [bar setHidden:NO];
    ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
    ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of figuring out the top navigation item on your own, you can obtain the one you're looking for from `viewController` variable passed to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method. Also, you can cache `doneButton` to avoid recreating it each time the top view controller of image picker changes:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
        willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
        animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!doneButton) {
        doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                      target:self action:@selector(saveImages:)];
    }

    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

Comment: thank you dude, you are amazing! I have been trying to get this simple thing done for that past 2 days with no luck.

Comment: No probs, you're welcome :) The bad thing about your code was probably that you modified view controller that was going away, and not the one that was coming on top (`bar.topItem` wasn't updated at the time you requested it). It should work if you handled the change in `didShowViewController` (and not `will...`). Anyway, this way seems simpler and does the job.